# preservative to use in falafel sauce

Tags: storage-method, storage

I have falafel sauce made of:

- dried red hot pepper
- fresh red bell pepper
- onion
- garlic
- lemon
- salt
- black pepper

I want to sell this product in glass bottles or plastic containers. What kind of preservative should I use?

Comment: How long of a shelf life are you hoping to have? Do you have a canning process to pasteurize the sauce and sterlilize the containers?

Comment: with the onion and garlic in there, you'll need to pressure can/bottle - there's no other safe way. to sell this product to people, you'll need to pressure can/bottle at a professional kitchen with the right professional equipment - there's no other safe way.

Answer (score 2):

As you're already using lemon (I assume the juice), and considering the tart/sour taste of citric acid would pair well with your ingredients; I would go for citric acid.

However food safety, especially when you're planning to commercially sell these products, is not something you should get direct advice from strangers on the Internet...

I wouldn't follow the guidance for the amounts and the processes mentioned here (or anywhere else). You really need professional opinion on creating shelf-stable food products. And you should be following professional food preservation techniques.

Comment: Talking directly to a food scientist is best before you try to market. This will cost you $$$.